# How to load local json data to Extjs data model

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

My ExtJS model is defined as below:

```
Ext.define("WinEvents", {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['eventName', 'domainId','eventId', 'proteanService', sviceId'],                            
    hasMany: { model: 'WinServices', name: 'services'},                         
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',  
        method:'GET',
        url : '../js/modules/tree_with_json/tree_model.json',  
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'events'
        }
    }
});
```

here, tree_model.json is blank file with suffix.json
I've variable named 'selectedEventsServices' and its value is having json data given as below.

```html
{
  "domainID" : "CONSUMERTELEMATICS_0.1",
  "domain" : "consumerTelematics",
  "tenantId": "4"
  "tenantName": "FOURRR"
  "tenantOUId": "13"
  "tenantOuName": "OSRTC Corp"
  "events" : [{
    "eventID" : "POS0.1",
    "event" : "pos0.1",
    "domainID" : "CONSUMERTELEMATICS_0.1",
    "services" : [{
        "proteanService" : "accident",
        "serviceID" : "SER_0.1_1",
        "domainID" : "CONSUMERTELEMATICS_0.1",
        "proteanRelatedService" : null,
        "eventID" : "POS0.1"
     },{
        "proteanService" : "assistanceService",
        "serviceID" : "SER_0.1_2",
        "domainID" : "CONSUMERTELEMATICS_0.1",
        "proteanRelatedService" : null,
        "eventID" : "POS0.1"
    }]
}]
 }
```

So As above mentioned value is dynamic, json structured data is saved to `selectedEventsServices` variable.
Now the question is how can I write, `selectedEventsServices` variable value to `tree_model.json` file?

or is there any way to get values from a variable while `Ext.data.Model` is called locally?

Comment: As far as i know, you cannot write local files with javascript ?

Comment: Yes,might be .. Then have you an idea , how can I approach this issue? Is there any way to fetch data from variable and load that data to ExtJS data Model directly?

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what exactly you like to do. But of course it is possible to create a Model from a variable. Look at the manual [Extjs.data.Model](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.data.Model)  for an example:

```
var user = Ext.create('User', {
    id : 'ABCD12345',
    name : 'Conan',
    age : 24,
    phone: '555-555-5555'
});
```